# Wocommerce no redirecciona al carrito

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Peleándome un poco con Woocommerce me pasa algo curioso, tengo copiado la carpeta `templates`a mi theme en la ruta `/miTema/woocommerce/`y he creado el fichero 
`woocommerce.php` con el código

```
<section class="contenedor-tienda">  
  <article class="listado-productos">
    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
  </article>
</section>
```

Ahí me lista los artículos demo y si pulso sobre ellos puedo ver su ficha detalle, añadirlos al carro y demás. Pero al pulsar para ver el carrito, me redirecciona al index, como si no existiese la página y no veo ningún tipo de error de php ni en el log de MAMP ni nada.

¿Me estaría faltando algún fichero o código en mi `woocommerce.php`? Porque no entiendo que no me pueda cargar la página del carrito.

Comment: ¿En la sección de `páginas` tienes una que esté definida como carrito?

Comment: ¿Podrías subir una imagen del árbol de ficheros y carpetas? Gracias

Comment: Gracias a ambos, parece que era un error en el fichero page.php de mi theme y por eso no cargaba.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que había un error en mi fichero `page.php` del tema que estoy construyendo y por eso me redireccionaba a la página del carrito.

He borrado todo lo que había en dicho fichero y hecho uno simple que muestre el contenido y ahora si redirecciona correctamente.